# Question on using templates in a class that has a struct members

Tags: c++, class, templates

I am trying to create a class (`myClass`) that has a private member (`Elements`) that is a vector of `myStruct`. `myStruct` is a structure that is using a template for defining its member `val`. I am getting an error:

```
error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> class std::vector’
   vector<myStruct> Elements;
```

which says that there is a mismatch. Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
struct myStruct {
  int i; 
  int j; 
  T val; 
};


class myClass {
  public:

  int m; 
  int n; 
  int num;
  vector<myStruct> Elements;

  private:

  SparseMatrix(int _m, int _n, int _num) : m(_m),  n(_n), num(_num) {
    this->Elements.resize(this->num);
  }
};
```

```
error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> class std::vector’
   vector<myStruct> Elements;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `myStruct` is a template class, you need to specify a type to instantiate it with.  Something like

```
vector<myStruct<int>> Elements;
```

to specify that your `myStruct` will hold an integer in its `val` field.

Comment: Thanks! Can I use the same type "T", i.e., vector<myStruct<T>> Elements in myClass?

Comment: @coffee `myClass` does not define a type `T` anywhere.  That's something you need to specify.

Answer (score 0):

As @1201ProgramAlarm stated the source of error is that type parameter for myStruct is not given. The corrected code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
struct myStruct {
  int i; 
  int j; 
  T val; 
};

template<class T>
class myClass {
  public:

  int m; 
  int n; 
  int num;
  vector<myStruct<T> > Elements;

  private:

  SparseMatrix(int _m, int _n, int _num) : m(_m),  n(_n), num(_num) {
    this->Elements.resize(this->num);
  }
};
```

Good luck!

Comment: Great, super helpful. Thanks!